# How to make Visual Basic applications run within a specific program?

Tags: vb.net

So I made this AutyoTyper in Visual Basic.  It's rather simple.  I write down the text I want it to type and then select how often I want the text to get typed.  Here is the code.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Timer1.Interval = TextBox2.Text * 1000


        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text)
        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

---

Is it possible to make this application that I have created to only run in a specific program.  I would for instance want it to run in a program while I do other stuff on the side without having the autotyper interrupt my other activities.  I want it to target a specific program.  Any tips?

Comment: Yes you can run this in a specific program and run other programs at the same time. I am not sure what you want.

Comment: I smell trouble.  You are either trying to hack passwords or something that isn't very useful.

Comment: Why is this tagged `C#`? I don't see the relevance. Removed tag.

Comment: @steve I don't think this is a useful criticism. As written, it is not a password hacker. Also I have done some useful things with SendKeys and have wished for the ability to do other things in the meantime.

Comment: Pete, look into windows api's that will allow you to search for a running application process.  That will give you insight into how to target a specific application, make it in focus, then use SendKeys.  It's not difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `SendKeys` the target program must have the focus. You cannot send keystrokes to a program that doesn't have the focus. So there is no way to avoid interrupting the work of the user when using SendKeys.

What you can do is use the API of the target program instead of using SendKeys. This only works if the target program has an API you can use.

For example: for Microsoft Excel or Word, you can write code that starts the program in the background and writes words to the sheet or page without these programs having the focus. Note that you wouldn't be using SendKeys for this to work. But I don't know of any way to do the same with Notepad. Many programs don't give you the ability to manipulate them in the background.

[SendKeys Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Be aware that the use of SendKeys can be dangerous. If the user clicks on the wrong window at the wrong time the output will be dumped to the newly active window instead of the intended one. Its use should be avoided if possible.